# PHP return value of $title variable from a flat file

Tags: php, fopen, fgets

I am working on a script that returns the literal value of the $title variable that is at the top of a `php` file. At the end of the script, I use `rtrim()` to get rid of the quote and semicolon at the end of the string however, they will not trim. The top of my `php` file looks like this:

```
<php
$title="Test Title";
$description="Test Description";
?>
```

When I echo the string, I get:

```
Test Title;"
```

Here is my code. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I'd even welcome any suggestions for improving this:

```
<?php
//returns the value of the $title variable from the top of a php file.
$file = fopen("test.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$count = 0;
while ($count < 10) {                   //only check the first 10 lines
    $line = fgets($file);
    $isTitle = strpos($line, "itle=");         //check if $title is part of the string
    if ($isTitle !== false) {
        $fullTitle = explode("=\"", $line);      //explode it into two on =" which also trims the first quote
        $untrimmedTitle = $fullTitle[1];         //save the second part of the array as a string since rtrim needs a string
        $title = rtrim($untrimmedTitle, "\";");    //trim the quote and semi-colon from the string 
        $count = 10;                               //push the count up to 10 so it ends the loop
    }
    $count++;
}
echo $title;                                //show the title
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: What about `include 'test.php'; echo $title;`...?

Comment: is that really the file, look at the miss-matched quotes

Comment: If you aim for a data file kind of thing, use JSON or YAML, something that's made for this purpose. Or even just old dumb INI will do a better job.

Comment: No, that is just the top of the file. Yes, I typed fast and mismatched a quote. Sorry about that. Any suggestions for why it won't trim?

Comment: I'm more concerned about why you'd even wanna do this.

Comment: Indeed, looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Aside from opinions about why you'd want to do it, fixing the quotes doesn't make a difference. rtrim still won't trim.

Comment: And by the way, that was an input error on my part when typing this up. The file does not have the error.

Comment: At least tell us why you're using this method over, say a relational database, or hell, even a flat file. It seems very inconvenient.

Comment: Also `<?php` not `<php` the syntax highlighting shows you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$title = rtrim($untrimmedTitle, "\";");` to `$title = rtrim(trim($untrimmedTitle), "\";");`. It will be fine.

At the end of $untrimmedTitle there is a break like `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

`$title = rtrim($untrimmedTitle, "\";");`

You're triming `"` and `;` from the string. You want to trim `'` and `;`:

`$title = rtrim($untrimmedTitle, "\';");`

**Edit:**

Why not just do:

```
include "test.php";
echo $title;
```

?

Comment: FIxed that and it still won't trim

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like :

```
$title = rtrim($untrimmedTitle, "\";\n");
```